# Testing Web Services Consumer

Tags: java, python, web-services, testing, integration-testing

Here are some tools that I have found to test web services consumers:

http://www.soapui.org/
https://wsunit.dev.java.net/

Are there any others? I would prefer testing frameworks that are written in Java or Python.

Answer (score 1):

I have used soapui by a maven plugin. It can create junit-linke reports to be run and analysed like unit tests. This can be easily integrated in continious build, also with the free distribution of soapui.

Answer (score 1):

I've  used [Web Service Studio](http://www.codeplex.com/WebserviceStudio).

> **Web Service Studio** is a tool to invoke web methods interactively. The
>   user can provide a WSDL endpoint. On clicking button Get the tool
>   fetches the WSDL, generates .NET proxy from the WSDL and displays the
>   list of methods available. The user can choose any method and provide
>   the required input parameters. On clicking Invoke the SOAP request is
>   sent to the server and the response is parsed to display the return
>   value.
>
> This tool is meant for web service implementers to test their web
>   services without having to write the client code. This could also be
>   used to access other web services whose WSDL endpoint is known.

Also the **Web Services Explorer** in Eclipse which comes as part of the [Web Tools Platform](http://www.eclipse.org/webtools/).

> Through UDDI and WSIL, other applications can discover WSDL documents
>   and bind with them to execute transactions or perform other business
>   processes. The Web Services Explorer allows you to explore, import,
>   and test WSDL documents.

Answer (score 0):

The Grinder is right up your ally with both Java and Python, that handles most web services, (SOAP/REST/CORBA/RMI/JMS/EJB) etc.

http://grinder.sourceforge.net/

Comment: Also, please be more descriptive in your questions in the future.  As there is many web testing frameworks, that tackle different aspects.

Answer (score 0):

You really need to be more specific: What is it that you want to test in your WS-consumer? That it calls the right WS? This looks a bit pointless - WS are a perfect place for mocking whatever may be called - without anything being called.

In order to test the consumer you'd otherwise be writing a Webservice that mocks the original, right? I'd suppose that the communication protocol that goes through the wire is not the clients domain - e.g. it's generated. So the only thing a WS-consumer's client sees is the interface. And there's nothing to test in an interface.

It might be that I completely misunderstood your question - please clarify if I did. I'll revise the answer then.